# Nltk Word Tokenizer in python notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nltk, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to find the frequenct words in a dataframe where each row consists of multiline string.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
tokens = [word for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(df['file_data'].to_string()) for 
         word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
```

[Most common word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBzcP.png)

Here, (...) as most common word but actually it doesn't present in any row.
By default, notebook on multi-line prints (...) to represent continuation.
But, the problem is nltk considers the (...) as word and ends with that. 
It skips the remaining words in the string. 
Please let me know where I'm missing, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like this is not the intended use of `to_string()`, which as far as I understand is meant for a console-friendly output (though I might be wrong).
How about:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
tokens = [word for row in df['file_data'].apply(nltk.sent_tokenize).values for sent in row for 
         word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
```

I'm not sure this would work as intended, if you post a short sample of the data I can check.